# How Do you add a dependecy to an apps gradle file?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hey guys recently I was reading an answer and I came across this

Add the following dependency to your app's Gradle file and run the application.

```
debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'
```

My question is this where do I paste this to?
I copied This to the build.gradle file in the android studio and I got a lot of errors saying

> ```
> Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'debugCompile()' Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'DB' may be using a version of the
> ```
>
> Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
>   'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade
>   plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
>
> The project 'DB'
>   may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The
>   build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Any Pointers on how to add a dependency would be appreciated! PS The official documentation just confuses me even more so please keep the answer simple Thanks :)

Comment: post your build.gradle files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the dependency inside the dependencies block in your **module** `build.gradle` ***not*** in your project `build.gradle`.

You can see the sample how adding the dependency from [UniversalMusicPlayer sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/build.gradle). Here the sample of **module** build.gradle without the license:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.uamp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
}
```

Take a look at the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
   ...
}
```

You need to add `debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'`
 there. So it will become:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0
}
```

Comment: Thank You This really helped me understand!